# Appending to div using Polymer function

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, polymer-1.0, firebase-realtime-database

I have a polymer web app conencted to a firebase database. I have successfully stored and retrieved the data to and from my database. I am trying to append a div to a dom-module during the Firebase forEach() method while parsing my JSON data from the database. I am getting this error though, and I am not really sure how else to append to my html code.

[image]

The error message says: "Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."

and this is the line that is throwing the error:

```
Polymer.dom(container).appendChild('<div class="card">' + data.name + '</div>');
```

Here is the rest of the code to give a little more context as to what I am trying to achieve with this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="my-list-view1">

    <template>
        <style>

            .cardContainer {
            }

            .card {
                box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
                padding-bottom: 16px;
                margin: 24px;
                border-radius: 5px;
                background-color: #fff;
                color: #757575;
            }

        </style>
        <div id="cardContainer">
            <paper-fab icon="arrow-forward" on-click="_loadJson"></paper-fab>
        </div>


    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer ({
            is: 'my-list-view1',
            _loadJson: function() {
                var ref = new Firebase("https://firebaseurl.com/entries");
                var container = this.$.cardContainer;
                ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
                    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                        var data = childSnapshot.val();
                        console.log(data.name + " " + data.phone);
                        Polymer.dom(container).appendChild('<div class="card">' + data.name + '</div>'); //error here
                    });
                });
            }
        })

    </script>

</dom-module>
```

The data is retrieved perfectly and I can parse through the JSON objects, but I am not sure how to append to this dom-module once I have the data. I really am trying to add a div for every json object to the div called cardContainer. All help is much appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I jumped the gun on this question. You have to use the function document.createElement() and then append that to the parent view that you want like so:

Here is my _loadJson function now:

_loadJson: function() {

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://firebaseurl.com/entries");
                var container = this.$.cardContainer;
                ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
                    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                        var data = childSnapshot.val();
                        console.log(data.name + " " + data.phone);
                        var card = document.createElement('div');
                        card.className = "card";
                        card.innerHTML = data.name + ", " + data.phone;
                        Polymer.dom(container).appendChild(card);
                    });
                });
            }
```

sorry If this is a duplicate, but anyone else with the same issue here is the solution.